# failed to create default crypt filter. Strange iOS CGPDFDOCUMENT wierdness

Tags: ios, pdf

I am getting the following error at the same place in my code

```
failed to create default crypt filter.
```

Just that, in lower case - no actual lines or anything, just this which looks like debug coming out of a library or something.

What my code does is opens an encrypted PDF, i have several, but for this one PDF, despite being the same encryption method can't open it and the only clue is this message.

The offending code is here:

```
        NSInteger pageCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(thePDFDocRef); //this one
        _pageCount = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:pageCount];
```

Here thePDFDocRef is of type CGPDFDocumentRef.

I have no idea why this happens, but it attempts to open the PDF (the same way it opens others) and just shows nothing, like I said the only clue is the crypt filter. Any ideas?

EDIT

I use a script to encrypt my PDF's here is the entry for this one:

```
qpdf --encrypt verybiglongpasswordwithonlylettersandnumbers verybiglongpasswordwithonlylettersandnumbers 128 --accessibility=y --modify=all -- FF-tm.pdf FF-tm/mff.pdf
```

the file mff only opens in preview (mac) and when i right click it through xcode - xcode crashes.

Something weird going on here.

EDIT EDIT

Running this from terminal gives me the following:

```
$> qpdf --check MFY-tm/mff.pdf --password=verybiglongpasswordwithonlylettersandnumbers
checking MFY-tm/mff.pdf
PDF Version: 1.6
R = 3
P = -4
User password = verybiglongpasswordwithonlylettersandnumbers
extract for accessibility: allowed
extract for any purpose: allowed
print low resolution: allowed
print high resolution: allowed
modify document assembly: allowed
modify forms: allowed
modify annotations: allowed
modify other: allowed
modify anything: allowed
File is not linearized
page 1: content stream object 615 0 (content, file position 3623): parse error while reading object
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the PDF file so we can take a look at it?

Comment: its sensitive so I can't sorry :( - i will add the command up above i use to create

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by re-exporting the original file.

I then encrypted the new file, ran a check and it worked.

My ios app could then open the PDF file as well. Turns out the corruption meant that preview could open it but ios couldn't and the only error message was:

```
failed to create default crypt filter.
```

Might leave this here incase someone googles there error/warning/debug message.